# Naming conflicts with Dummy variables in several packages conflicts

Tags: packages, variable-definitions, contexts

I'm using several packages in a notebook. In each packages there is functions defined with dummy variables. When I load the several packages in my session, i've got a warning message:

```
BeginPackage["square`"];
square[x_] := x^2;
EndPackage[]
BeginPackage["cube`"];
cube[x_] := x^3;
EndPackage[]
```

> x::shdw: Symbol x appears in multiple contexts {cube`,square`};
>   definitions in context cube` may shadow or be shadowed by other
>   definitions. >>

I don't really understand since the variable `x` should be dummy ?

Comment: That's why you should write definitions in additional ``Begin["`Private`"] ... End[];`` statements. Symbols created there are not exported outside since End does not modify `$ContextPath`.

Comment: [SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html)

Comment: I used that before and I just notice that I had a syntax error : `Begin["Private``"]` instead of `Begin["``Private``"]`. Thank you @Kuba

Comment: Np. p.s. you need double `` to escape ` from inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things you need to know:

(1.) Mathematica knows about symbols, even if you only *mention* them: This means that in this simple example

```
1 /. myVar_Integer :> 0
```

where `myVar` is only a placeholder (a named pattern) or like you call it *a dummy*, *Mathematica* still sees this symbol and adds it to its symbol table

```
Names["Global`*"]
(* {"myVar"} *)
```

(2.) Since a context created with `BeginPackage` is added to the `$ContextPath` when you call `EndPackage`, all symbols created there are accessible after loading the package. Therefore, the general rule when creating packages is to protect most internal code (like your definition) within another private context introduced with `Begin`.

Therefore, what you should do is to use the usual boiler-plate code until you understood all implications:

```
BeginPackage["cube`"];
cube::usage = "cube";
Begin["`Private`"];
cube[x_] := x^2;
End[];
EndPackage[];
```